# Pycharm using base interpreter when configured to use virtualenv interpreter

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pycharm

I have configured PyCharm (v3.4.1) on a Windows 7 machine to use a virtualenv, which has Django 1.7 as one of its packages.

My base interpreter is at `C:\Python27\python.exe` and uses Django 1.6.

I have configured PyCharm to use my virtualenv with Django 1.7 using these steps:
`Settings`--> `Project Interpreter`--> [select virtualenv with Django 1.7] --> OK --> [wait for PyCharm to re-index]

When my Django error page (debug is on) shows up, it says it's running Django 1.6.  Also, when I test the Django version in the console, it says it's running Django 1.6.

What can I do to force PyCharm to use the packages within the virtualenv?

Here are my Interpreter Paths:

```
[virtualenv path]\Lib
[virtualenv path]\Scripts
C:\Python27\Lib
C:\Python27\DLLs
C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk
[virtualenv path]
[virtualenv path]\Lib\site-packages
```

Comment: Have you set up where your `settings.py` locates in [Preferences] -> [Django]?

Comment: I did not have the location for settings.py in place.  I do now, thank you, but I have restarted everything and I am still getting the same results.

Comment: if not working on DJANGO environment this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/32175335/2772269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I configure my PyCharm:

1. [Preferences] -> [Django]: set up ***Django project root*** (this is the directory   including your app folder and virtualenv folder), the location of `settings.py` and `manage.py`
2. [Preferences] -> [Project Interpreter]: specify your interpreter; if you use virtualenv, it would be something like **Python 3.4.2 virtualenv at ~/path_to_your_project/your_project_name/your_virtualenv_name**
3. [Run] -> [Edit Configurations]: check if ***Python interpreter*** is set the same as what you set in step 2 and the ***working directory*** is configured as where your app locates; also, you should see the ***Environment variables*** has been set to **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=your_app_name.settings**

Moreover, if this doesn't work, you might try to remove this project in PyCharm and recreate it and set up again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Step #3 is what did the trick!  Specifically, I needed to "[Run] -> [Edit Configurations]: check if if Python interpreter is set the same as what you set in step 2."  I did this and it's using my virtual environment.  I did thought that the project interpreter was the project environment, but apparently this is not true.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to configure the "Interpreter path" to your virtualenv/bin/python when build your virtualenv