# Pycharms debugger running on a different Python interpreter in subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, pycharm

I have a PyCharms python project configured to run on a virtual env (Python 2.7.9).
Off late , trying to debug the project on PyCharms used to throw import errors for many modules. The code works just fine when invoked from a command prompt running same virtual env or while "Run"ing the project from PyCharms. Upon inspection I found that for some reason PyCharms is invoking Python 2.7.10 and probably the third party dependencies are not installed in there !.

My Question is, Is there a reason why PyCharms is moving away from the virtual env when invoking subprocess and what would be the best way to overcome this problem.

Here is the output of main process and subprocess when running from console/pycharms for the command

```
print __import__("sys").version

Sys version from Main Process!
2.7.9 (default, Feb 10 2015, 03:28:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)]

Sys version from Sub Process!
2.7.9 (default, Feb 10 2015, 03:28:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)]
```

And this is the output while debugging from the PyCHarms

```
print __import__("sys").version

Sys version from Main Process!
2.7.9 (default, Feb 10 2015, 03:28:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)]

Sys version from Sub Process!
2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)]
```

PyCharms version:
PyCharms Community edition 4.5.3[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update with MacOSX ElCaptian update

With the introduction of new rootless feature with OSX ElCaptian (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really) , it is no longer possible to alter python at /usr/bin , instead the better approach would be to just update PATH env variable from run configuration (Run->Edit Configuration->Environment->EnvironmentVariable and add/update PATH variable to /usr/local/bin:$PATH)
[image]

---

### other way around

With little tinkering I was able to resolve the issue , may be it's not the correct way but it did solve the issue for me.

PyCharms while debugging somehow used invoke python from /usr/bin/ having python 2.7.10 instead of python 2.7.9 from /usr/local/bin . Since All my path settings are correct and I do not rely upon 2.7.10 ,I rename python in "/usr/bin/" to python2.7.10 and created a symbolic link to python from /usr/local/bin in "/usr/bin" folder.

PyCharms now works like charm , but I still do not understand why it used to refer an external python bypassing the PATH settings and more-over why it has to invoke a python interpreter outside virtualenv when running a subprocess. Any idea's or hints on these questions are highly appreciated.